# Trigger Test Class - Error: Missing ID

Tags: trigger

I am writing a test class on trigger which deletes a record if cancelled checkbox is selected on record detail page.

In my test class, I am trying to set the cancel checkbox to true and delete the record but getting error: "Missing id at index: 0" for the line `delete erc;`

```
@istest private class cancelEvent_test {
    testMethod private static void testCancelERC(){

        //insert Event
        event__c testEvent = TestData.nEvent(1);
        insert testEvent;

        //insert contact
        contact testContact = TestData.nContact(1);
        insert testContact;

        //assign newly created event and contact to ERC
        Event_Registered_Contact__c ERC = new Event_Registered_Contact__c(event__c = testEvent.id, Contact__c = testContact.id);
        ERC.Cancel__c = true;
        delete erc;
        /*
        try{
            delete erc;
        } catch (system.DMLException e) {
            system.assert(e.getmessage().contains('Hello'));
        }
        */        
    }
}
```

TestData Class:

```
@istest public class TestData{        
    //Create a new Contact
    public static contact nContact(integer i){
        contact nContact = new contact();
        nContact.FirstName = 'contact'+i;
        nContact.LastName = 'name'+i;
        nContact.Email = 'contact'+i+'@gmail.com';
        return nContact;
    }

    //Create a new Event
    public static Event__c nEvent(integer i){
        Event__c nEvent = new Event__c();
        nEvent.name = 'Test_Event'+i;
        return nEvent;
    }
}
```

Also, I just began writing test classes after learning from internet, Can you please look into the code and suggest me any improvements

Comment: if you can share your Apex class then it would be easy for us to understand that what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: You first need to insert ERC before you can delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert a record before you can delete it, as mentioned in the comments. You also have a flaw in your test, because it looks like you are hoping the delete fails, but if it doesn't your test will pass. A better pattern would be more like the following:

```
DmlException expectedException;
try
{
    delete erc;
}
catch (DmlException dmx)
{
    expectedException = dmx;
}

system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException);
```

This way if there is no `DmlException`, the test will fail.

Comment: Actually, I am expecting delete to pass

Comment: Then you would change it to `unexpectedException` and `assertEquals`.